# InkWell For a WIdget List?

Tags: list, listview, animation, flutter, dart

i want to add the inkwell animation for the side bar in flutter but i don not want to add them for each item is there any way to add inkwell to all items in a list without doing it one by one, (i added it to the first one list view widget).
if it is not possible, then is there any widget that can do the job ?   thanks

code :)

```
class SideBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          child: Center(
              child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
        ),
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.person),
            title: Text('Account'),
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
          title: Text('Settings'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.transit_enterexit),
          title: Text('Exit'),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ListTile` has an `onTap` parameter that will add the same animation as `InkWell`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("My Home Page")),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
      body: Center(child: const Text("My Home Page")),
    );
  }
}

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
          title: const Text('Account'),
          onTap: () {},
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: const Icon(Icons.settings),
          title: const Text('Settings'),
          onTap: () {},
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Very clarifying, didn't find this info in docs ( surely I didn't look well). idk why but mine isn't showing any animation, tried even embrace each ListTile with InkWell but that didn't solve the problem